# Create a Normal Non-Managed Schema in Solr

Tags: solr

I have been scouring the internet trying to figure out how to create a Solr collection that does not use the managed schema. I want to be able to create what I am going to call a normal collection where I have to manually modify the schema.xml file to define the fields that I want to use.

I have tried the following commands:

```
sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c collection_name -n data_driven_schema_configs

sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c collection_name -n basic_configs"
```

I am attempting to do this in a Vagrantfile where I can then just point my other developers at the schema.xml file and they can then dive in and enter their fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by using the following command:

```
sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create_core -d basic_configs -c collection_name"
```

Comment: Note: This appears to not work in Solr 5.5.3